# Workbox wbepack encore dont work (in symfony 4 application)

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony4, workbox, webpack-encore

I apologize if the question already was to find, and that it has an answer, but in research on intenert, I did not find anything which worked.

Here is my problem, I started with workbox, and I tried to integrate it into my Symfony 4 application which still uses webpack, but it does not work properly. So I tried to generate the service worker with the cli, but I still can't get it to work.

My webpack encore configuration:

```js
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const {GenerateSW, InjectManifest} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path')

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('cart', './assets/js/cart.js')
    .addEntry('site', './assets/js/site.js')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .enableSassLoader()
    .enableVueLoader(() => {}, { runtimeCompilerBuild: false })
    .addLoader({
        test: /\.exec\.js$/,
        loader: 'script-loader'
    })
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .autoProvideVariables({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    })
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .addPlugin(new CompressionPlugin())
    .addPlugin(new GenerateSW({swDest:  'sw.js'}))
    .addPlugin(new InjectManifest({
        swSrc: 'sw.js',
        exclude: [
            /\.map$/,
            /manifest$/,
            /\.htaccess$/,
            /service-worker\.js$/,
            /sw\.js$/,
        ],
    }));



module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

for webpack generate error i have found this: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1513 but

After cli generateSW i have this error:

```
 error 

Can't find self.__WB_MANIFEST in your SW source.
```

for wb manifest i have found this: 
[Webpack workbox Can't find self.__WB_MANIFEST in your SW source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60491114/webpack-workbox-cant-find-self-wb-manifest-in-your-sw-source) but doesn't work for me

I think the problem comes from the url generated by webpack and i have found this: 
[Can't install service worker of workbox-webpack-plugin in root url for React app, it's installing at localhost:8080/dist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53423574/cant-install-service-worker-of-workbox-webpack-plugin-in-root-url-for-react-app) 
But I don't see how it helps me in my configuration.

I have tried with path.resolve (because on forum i have seen work), but don't work for me, i get this error:

```
Can't find self.__WB_MANIFEST in your SW source.
```

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';
// Your other import statements go here.

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
```

On your sw.js

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this works and why it is the solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].

Comment: actually this not works